# Setting error message to right side of control bootstrap and Angular Js

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular js, in which i have the below control.

```
<body class="ng-cloak">
    <div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
        <form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate="">

            <div class="container form-horizontal" ng-show="createMenu">
                <br />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="form-control" required="" ng-model="nName" id="nName" name="nName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <span class="error" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.nName.$error.required">Please enter Name.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Recipient Group:<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
                    <div class="input-group col-sm-4" style="padding-left:10px;">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Search the group" ng-model="searchDatalocation" ng-change="searchgroups()" name="searchValue">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <span class="error" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.searchValue.$error.required">Please select a Recipient group.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

The error message "Please enter Name" appears on right side of the textbox, however, the error message "Please select a Recipient group" appers below the control. I have tried changing the css, but it has not worked. How to set the error message to be shown on right side after the control.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the `.input-group` div with `display: inline-table;` and `float:left;`

Please also note that there is one missing closing tag `</div>` for `class="container form-horizontal"`